# Search through a 2D array and return the entire row

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I am new to C++ and I am having a hard time figuring out how 2D arrays work.

I am making a program that takes a `.txt` file filled with "driver's license records" and reads them in, and then lets the user search through the "database" for for last name, age, or whether the driver is registered to vote (y/n).

A sample `.txt` file would look like this:

```
4
Chris Jones 19 Y 374122
Pat Smith 23 N 863901
Kyle Howard 31 Y 673911
Samantha Pratter 27 Y 874309
```

My main method is simply

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
Executive exec(argv[1]);
exec.run();
return (0);
}
```

Here is the code for my `Executive` class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Executive.h"
#include "DriversLicenseRecord.h"
using namespace std;

Executive::Executive(char* filename){

    int n;
    ifstream inp(filename);

    inp >> n;
    num_records=n;

    DriversLicenseRecord** record = new DriversLicenseRecord*[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        record[i] = new DriversLicenseRecord(inp);
    }

}
//here is where I am pretty much guessing
void Executive::run(){
    int x=0;
    do{
        cout << "1: Query last name" << endl << "2: Query age range" << endl << "3: Query registered voters" << endl << "4: Quit" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        if(x==1){
            string name;
            cout << "Enter last name: ";
            cin >> name;
            /**for(int i=0; i<num_records; i++){
                if(name==record[i]){
                    cout << record[i];
                }
            }*/
        }
        else if(x==2){
            int max;
            int min;
            cout << "Enter age range: " << endl << "min: ";
            cin >> min;
            cout << "max: ";
            cin >> max;

        }
        else if(x==3){
        }
    }while(x!=4);
}
```

And here is my `DriversLicenseRecord` class:

```
#include "DriversLicenseRecord.h"
using namespace std;

DriversLicenseRecord::DriversLicenseRecord(ifstream& inp){
    inp >> first_name;
    inp >> last_name;
    inp >> age;
    inp >> vote;
    inp >> license;
}
```

Firstly I want to know if I'm reading in the values correctly, it is my understanding that it skips reading in white space, so the `DriversLicenseRecord` should be getting the correct values.

Secondly I have no idea how to search through this, and return the whole row.

Below is an example of output with a given `.txt` file:

```
1. Query last name
2. Query age range
3. Query registered voters
4. Quit

3 // user input

Chris Jones 19 Y 374122

Kyle Howard 31 Y 673911

Samantha Pratter 27 Y 874309
```

Just a small push in the right direction would be very helpful, I've been struggling with this problem all week and haven't made much progress.

Thank you!

Comment: What's your logic for why you need to use a 2D array here? To be more precise: what is 2D about your data structure?

Comment: My TA told me that DriversLicenseRecord** record = new DriversLicenseRecord*[n]; is effectively making a 2D array. I'm brand new at pointers and all of this so I'm sorry if I'm asking the wrong questions

Comment: No, not this. Look at the actual problem. Why do you think it requires using 2D array?

Comment: I suppose an array to hold the entries and an array within each to hold name, age, etc. Because how can you store strings and ints all in one index of a 1D array?

Comment: Doable, but look you already have a class called `DriversLicenseRecord` to store the actual details of a singler entry. Besides, you can't easily store entries of different data types in an array in C++.

Comment: all you need is an array of strings....your TA should have told you that in the first place. And even that is just one approach not the only approach

Comment: There is a mistake in your code, let me post a complete answer.

Comment: What you have here is not a 2D array. `record` is a pointer to a 1 D array of pointers to `DriversLicenseRecord` objects. There are many better ways to do this ([`std::vector<DriversLicenseRecord>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) being one), but I suspect that's not the point of the assignment. `record`'s big sin is it's a local variable and will be lost as soon as the constructor exits. All that memory to which it pointed will be lost with it. `record` needs to be a member variable of the `Executive` class.

Comment: @user4581301 you beat me to it. But if you don't mind I'll post a standard library based solution soon. Didn't want to post an incomplete answer as this turns out to be prohibited.

Comment: Go ahead, @iksemyonov . Warning though, this has the smell of a no STL  containers assignment. I recommend a brief addendum to your answer to handle some of the questions OP may have porting the vector to the pointer horrorshow their instructor seems to want.

Comment: Well you know some folks seem to like to answer "how to loop trough this" with 10 lines of mindboggling c++11 STL.. which actually does make sense after all! On a serious note, I'll add a warning, note taken.

Comment: @user4581301, finally got the code working (I haven't coded for years..) Take a look if you wish. Can be made neater with some functors I think.

Comment: Sidenote to all you teachers, professors, ... out there who come up with such homework assignments: Why try to do business programming in a system language? Why not give this type of assignments for your haskell/ocaml/... classes and find good c++ system programming examples for the c++ class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple errors in your code, but first I'd like to say that there is (1) no need for a 2D array here and (2) you don't create a 2D array in `Executive::Executive()`. For (1): all you need in this task is an one-dimensional array (or container) of `DriversLicenseRecord` objects. Then, you can query the  fields of individual objects and compare their values to the query to search for specific records. For (2), what you have created is simply an one-dimensional array of pointers to `DriversLicenseRecord` objects.

Here is where the errors appear.

Firstly, the variable `records` is local to the constructor. Once the c'tor returns, `records` will be destroyed. You won't be able to access it outside the constructor. Also, the memory you allocated will be lost, creating a memory leak.

Secondly, while creating the array is correct, iteration is not. Here's how you can iterate over the array and query the fields:

```
for(int i=0; i < num_records; i++){
   // note the -> : because we're using a pointer, not the object itself
   if(name == m_records[i]->first_name){
       cout << m_records[i]->first_name;
       // or, if you define operator<<(istream&, const DriversLicenseRecord&):
        cout << *(m_records[i]);
   }
```

Finally, why you had to use a dynamic array. Thing is, you don't know the number of entries until you read the file, and you can't create a variable length array other than with `new`, except inside a function as a local variable, but then see #1: it's lost on function exit. However, you could create a dynamic array of records, not pointers to records. For that, you need to supply a default constructor to `DriversLicenseRecord`, and then simply fill in the fields on the fly from the file. (Not the syntax you used with `DriversLicenseRecord::DriversLIcenseRecord(istream&)`, that's not the default c'tor.)

Next, this is how I would go about this problem, using STL containers and algorithms.

**1.** Switch to `std::vector`, which has the benefit of being safer and more convenient to use.

**2.** I honestly disliked the idea of creating the `D.L.R.` class with an `istream` parameter. What you can do, if you want to use streams, is to define `istream& operator>>(istream&, DriverLicenseRecord&)` and then use the beautiful STL syntax like so:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, DriversLicenseRecord& rec)
{
    std::string str;
    str >> rec.first_name >> rec.last_name >> rec.age >> temp >> rec.license;
    rec.can_vote = (temp == "Y");
    return str;
}
```

Then some STL beauty:

```
class Executive {
    typedef std::istream_iterator<DriversLicenseRecord> in_driver_it;
    std::vector<DriversLicenseRecord> records;
public:
    Executive(const std::string& file)
    {
        std::ifstream inp(file);
        int n; inp >> n;
        std::copy(in_driver_it(inp), in_driver_it(), std::back_inserter(records));
    }
};
```

Same fot the output.

Long story short: [here is the complete sample code using the standard library](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43f0b6d6e684747d), which is not the shortest but simple on the other hand. Running out of space!

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time for all of that. However, why is it that simply by changing `DriversLicenseRecord** record = new DriversLicenseRecord*[n];` to `DriversLicenseRecord* record = new DriversLicenseRecord[n];` I go from compiling just fine to getting hundreds of errors?

Comment: @G.Petter, see my fix above. I made a silly mistake with array syntax. Yours was correct but unnecessarily complex, just use a `std::vector<>`.

Comment: @G.Petter however then your syntax for iteration in `run()` is slightly wrong. Let me redo the answer a little bit to first address your existing code and only then suggest my approach.

Comment: @G.Petter see the final version! I made it much better by actually going through your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using the 2D array. 
**Approach 1**
Use a `vector<string>` instead. Makes things much simpler to handle.
Read from the text file and store each line as a string in the vector.

Then when you are searching for a particular query string all you need to do is process each string in the vector.

So for reading from the input text file you would do something like this:

```
ifstream inpFile(myfile.txt);
string line;
vector<string> myInpFile;
while(getline(inpFile,line))
{     
 myInpFile.push_back(line);
}
```

I'll leave the implementation of the string search as an exercise for you. Take a look at how to process strings [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

**Approach 2**
Alternatively you can just read off what you need straight off the file into a string and then search the string. You wouldn't need `DriversLicenseRecord` in memory at all. But that's not what your TA appears to be looking for.

Comment: Storing all the data as a big string isn't a very good solution to this problem. It complicates the searching. Now OP has to search a delimited section of a string to find the result.

Comment: in my first approach all the data is not stored as a _big string_. Its split into a vector of strings. There's a difference from approach 2.